# What does the superscript "$+$" mean? $(2-x_1^2)^{+} = \max(0,(2-x_1^2)^{+})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, dynamic-programming

While I am doing a dynamic programming exercise, the suggested answer gives me this:
$$(2-x_1^2)^{+} = \max(0,(2-x_1^2)^{+})$$

Why they are equal and what does the plus sign mean?

Comment: Well, the second $+$ shouldn't be there...once corrected, that equality is the definition.  That is, for any $z\in \mathbb R$ we have $z^+=\max(0, z)$.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a "standard" notation but the right side of the equation (without the "+" as lulu says) that is the function that is positive when f(x) is positive, 0 when f(x) is 0 or negative.

Comment: Worth noting:  if the second $+$ sign is actually intended, then the equation is certainly true, as $z^+≥0$ for all $z$.  But I suspect it's a typo and the writer intended to give the definition.

Comment: oh it is my false the right hand side + it doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

$h^{+}(x)$ is the function where $h^{+}(x) = h(x)$ iff $h(x) \ge 0$, and where $h^{+}(x) = 0$ iff $h(x) \le 0$.